# How to aggregate in SQL by having clause

Tags: sql

The below is the query I'm using, I would like to add two more columns in the select statement which I have and noted them in the group by clause but the total results are different.  The below script gives me the correct total count but I want to see the totals also for  a column called transaction, and a column called employee.  The total count should still be the same.

```
SELECT SUB.YEAR, SUM(SUB.TOTAL_COUNT), SUM(SUB.TOTAL_SPENT)
FROM (
      SELECT YEAR, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_COUNT, SUM($SPENTX) AS TOTAL_SPENT, CUSTOMERID
      FROM TABLE A
      WHERE YEAR = 2017
      GROUP BY YEAR, CUSTOMERID
      HAVING SUM($SPENTX)<=1000
      ) SUB
GROUP BY SUB.YEAR
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired resuts, otherwise it is hard to tell what you exactly want.

Comment: How do you define your columns called "transaction" and "employee"?  They have nothing to do with the query you have shown.

Comment: Could you tag DB Engine?